# Spring Data JPA: FindBy on Join Column

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have setup two entities like below in a one-to-one mapping and I am trying to query on the joincolumn like below in my repository:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class A extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String name;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class B extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="aId", referencedColumnName = "aId")
    private A aId;

}
```

In my `BRepository.java`, I am trying to do this:

```
@Component
public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<B, Long> {
    List<B> findAllBByA_aId(String aId);
}
```

I get the following error:

`No property a found for type B! Did you mean 'aId'?`

Is this not the right way to query on a join column in spring-data??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have not defined the column name for `id` in A then the column name will defaults to `id`. Then in class B, you should change the `referencedColumnName` to `id` (or else you can simply skip the `referencedColumnName` attribute since it can be derived directly from the target entity in an OneToOne relationship)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class B extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="aId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private A aId;

}
```

In repository, you need to annotate it with `@Repository` annotation to let Spring know it should be treated as a Repository Bean.

```
@Repository
public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<B, Long> {
    
    @Query(value="select b from B b where B.aId.id=?1")
    List<B> findAllBByA_aId(String aId);
}
```

or you can use SPeL directly,

```
@Repository
public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<B, Long> {
    
    List<B> findAllByaIdId(String aId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the below @Query worked for me. After the 'WHERE' I used the instance and not the Repository name. Basically, I had to use lowercase 'b' and not uppercase 'B'

`@Query(value="select b from B b where b.aId.id=?1")`